# Цвет иконки в Toolbar

Tags: android

В шаблоне `Navigation Drawer Activity` заменил исходный Toolbar на свой и разместил в нем нужные компоненты. Но иконка меню стала черной, вместо белой. Подскажите, как сделать ее белой?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Нашел решение.

```
<style name="ToolbarColoredBackArrow" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">INSERT_COLOR_HERE</item>
</style>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
```